# create relationships for STI child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have User, Teacher and ClassRomm model using STI as following

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Teacher < User
  has_many :class_rooms
end

class Student < User
  has_many_and_belongs_to :class_rooms
end

class ClassRoom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teachers
  has_many_and_belongs_to :students
end
```

my question how can i create **migration** **for all relationships between user,teacher,Student and classRooms** ?

for example should class_rooms has forignKey column for instructor_id or user_id

Answer (score 0):

first of all

in `ClassRoom` association should be singular `belongs_to :teacher`, without `s`

also `ClassRoom` mast have column `teacher_id`, than create "third" table with name `ClassRoomsStudents` for `has_many_and_belongs_to` association

and it should works